# Select all unique values of all attributes in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table and I want to select all unique values of all attributes in one query.

For example table `Person` with 3 columns `name, age, city`.

Example:

| Name | age | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 34 | New York |
| Leo | 34 | London |
| Roy | 20 | London |
| Alex | 28 | Moscow |
| Mike | 36 | London |

And I want to have a result with unique values of every attribute

| Name | age | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 20 | New York |
| Leo | 28 | London |
| Roy | 34 | Moscow |
|  | 36 |  |

Is it possible to do this query?

I tried to make some queries with `DISTINCT` and `UNION`, but the result with always a multiplication of rows.

Comment: You shouldn't do this kind of operation in a DBMS. Better to do such with higher-level programming, for example with a python script using pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how relational databases work, but sometimes you got to do what you got to do.

You can do:

```
select a.name, b.age, c.city
from (select distinct name, row_number() over() as rn from t) a
full join (select distinct age, row_number() over() as rn from t) b on b.rn = a.rn
full join (select distinct city, row_number() over() as rn from t) c
  on c.rn = coalesce(a.rn, b.rn)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to aggregate into array, then unnest those arrays:

```
select x.*
from (
  select array_agg(distinct name) as names, 
         array_agg(distinct age) as ages,
         array_agg(distinct city) as cities
  from the_table
) d
  cross join lateral unnest(d.names, d.ages, d.cities) with ordinality as x(name, age, city);
```

I would expect this to be quite slow if you really have many distinct values ("millions"), but if you only expect very few distinct values ("hundreds" or "thousands") , then this might be OK.